# Doctrine \ ORM \ EntityManager, unspecified in class MessageComponentInterface

Tags: php, symfony, ratchet

i'm using Ratchet websocket library in my project on symfony 2.8.
my problem is how to define the entity manager that exist in another controller's methode.

```
class WesocketController implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        echo $msg;
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        $myController = new OtherController();
        $myController->test();

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My function in the othe controller:

```
public function test()
{
    // echo('yassine');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $newTest = new VisitsTest();
    $newVisitsTest
        ->setTestDate(new \DateTime())
        ->setClient(null);
    $em->persist($newTest);
    $em->flush();
}
```

ERROR:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has() on null in MyApp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php
```

The error is on this line in the other controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

PLease help how to resolve this problem

Thanks

Comment: It implies that your "other" controller is not really a controller and is just a class that you assume will act like a controller because it extends the base Controller class. The service container is not being injected.  Look in the 2.8 docs to understand what a service is and how to define one.

Answer (score 0):

For controller actions, consider [Autowirring your services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

```
public function test(EntityManagerInterface $em){
       $newTest = new VisitsTest();
            $newVisitsTest
                ->setTestDate(new \DateTime())
                ->setClient(null);
            $em->persist($newTest);
            $em->flush();
}
```

That way, you won't open a new EntityManager for every action you're calling